# replacing a character in a date with space in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i am new to javascript.I was dealing with a json which has a field-

```
    "updated_time": "2013-03-16T05:33:57+0000",
```

I want to replace T with a space in this field.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function will do that:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/XsW5C/)

```
//Your JSON string
var json = '{"updated_time": "2013-03-16T05:33:57+0000"}'; 

//Parse the string into object    
var o = JSON.parse(json);                                  

//Replace T in timestamp with space
o["updated_time"] = o["updated_time"].replace('T',' ');    

//Show result
alert(o["updated_time"]);
```

Comment: i wasn't allowed to accept your answer..it says i can do it after 2 minutes..will surely do it.